# Get played action name

Tags: python, game-engine

I need to get current playing action name in python. something like .getActionFrame() but with Name instead of Frame
Does it exists? If not, can someone tell me how to get current played action name?

> if Arma.getActionFrame(3) >= 20 and Arma.getActionFrame(3) <= 28 ***and Arma.getActionName(3) == "Action1"***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wished, you got it. You can use it exactly as you wrote it:

```
print(Arma.getActionName(3))
/// Action1
```

[Here](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_release/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.getActionName) is the API.

[Here](https://developer.blender.org/D1443) is the commit (in August 2015 by Mateo de Mayo (@mateosss)).